# paging in WP_Query on static page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, paginate-links

I have a static page, and on that page I want to show a listing of blog posts. I want 12 posts per page (so I want the listing to be paginated).

It's all working great, except for the pagination. Here's my code:

```
    <section id="blogposts" class="content-block content-3-5 blogposts">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Feature Box 1 -->
                <?php
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $blogposts_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'nopaging' => false,
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'posts_per_page' => '12',
                        'paged' => $paged
                    )
                    ?>
                <?php $blogposts = new WP_Query( $blogposts_args ); ?>
                <?php if ( $blogposts->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php $blogposts_item_number = 0; ?>
                    <?php while ( $blogposts->have_posts() ) : $blogposts->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
                        $url = $thumb['0'];
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="feature-box">
                                <div class="column-item-category"><?php the_category(); ?></div>
                                <a class="feature-box-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( '', array(
                                            'class' => 'column-circle'
                                        ) ); ?>
                                </a>
                                <a class="feature-box-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <h4 class="column-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                </a>
                                <p class="column-item-author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $blogposts_item_number++; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>'; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>'; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 1 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>'; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <div class="post-nav-links">
                        <div class="prev-post"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
                        <div class="next-post"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- Feature Box 2 -->
                <!-- Feature Box 3 -->
                <!-- Feature Box 4 -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Ends -->
    </section>
```

Like I said -- everything works fine. Except no pagination links show up. I'm posting this at the risk of total embarrassment, since I'm pretty positive I'm missing something really basic. But I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure it out, and that seems to be the right time to ask on here. Anyway... any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have edited your code a bit. And i think it should work.You need to pass parameters to previous_posts_link and next_posts_link.

So try the following code

```
<section id="blogposts" class="content-block content-3-5 blogposts">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Feature Box 1 -->
                <?php
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $blogposts_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'nopaging' => false,
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'posts_per_page' => '12',
                        'paged' => $paged
                    )
                    ?>
                <?php $blogposts = new WP_Query( $blogposts_args ); ?>
                <?php if ( $blogposts->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php $blogposts_item_number = 0; ?>
                    <?php while ( $blogposts->have_posts() ) : $blogposts->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
                        $url = $thumb['0'];
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="feature-box">
                                <div class="column-item-category"><?php the_category(); ?></div>
                                <a class="feature-box-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( '', array(
                                            'class' => 'column-circle'
                                        ) ); ?>
                                </a>
                                <a class="feature-box-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <h4 class="column-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                </a>
                                <p class="column-item-author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $blogposts_item_number++; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>'; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>'; ?>
                        <?php if( $blogposts_item_number % 1 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>'; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <div class="post-nav-links">
                        <div class="prev-post"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer', $blogposts->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
                        <div class="next-post"><?php next_posts_link('Older', $blogposts->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- Feature Box 2 -->
                <!-- Feature Box 3 -->
                <!-- Feature Box 4 -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Ends -->
    </section>
```